# why doesn't my 4th gen ipod have the camera app anymore?

Tags: applications, ipod-touch, ipod, camera, ipod.app

I restored my iPod because it had system failures and even the settings app crashed. Now after restoring it using my backup there is no camera app despite me having it before. Do I have to restore it as a new iPod? Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: I would recommend restoring as a new device. Did you apply any jailbreak before any of this happened?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the iPod has restored from backup incorrectly, I would do a factory reset and then sync again as a new device.

You will then need to select what apps, music etc you want to sync. It may be worthwhile deleting the first backup to stop this coming into play again.